# Updating the sheets with other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am having three Sheets, Sht1 having my Basic data, sht2, having an data from last week, sht3 having an data with present week.

I am copying the data from sht1 to sht3, which ever has an Status red in columnJ. 
After copying, i look into the lastweek sht and check for value in L and then fill the column N,O,P in sheet thisweek.

In the next step, whenever i click a button, the lastweeksht should be update by the data in present week sheet and present week should be deleted and evaluated with the new result. How can i do it. I should  do the last step of moving the data to last week and updating thisweek to new result ? I am confused how to do this.

below are the codes, where i am using for copying the Status from Basic sht to this week and the vlookup formula i am using in thisweek.

```
Sub red()
Dim cell As Range
Dim nextrow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Sheets("Red").Range("J5:J" & Sheets("Red").Cells(Sheets("Red").Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
If cell.Value = "rd" Then
nextrow = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Sheets("ThisWeek").Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub lookup()
Dim tr As Long
Dim trsh As Long
tr = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
trsh = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("M2:M" & tr).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("L2:L" & trsh), Sheets("LastWeek").Range("$A:$P"), 13, 0), "")
End Sub

Sub lookupredaction()
Dim tr1 As Long
Dim trsh1 As Long
tr1 = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
trsh1 = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("N2:N" & tr1).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("L2:L" & trsh1), Sheets("LastWeek").Range("$A:$P"), 14, 0), "")
End Sub

Sub lookupredoverdue()
Dim tr2 As Long
Dim trsh2 As Long
tr2 = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
trsh2 = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("O2:O" & tr2).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("L2:L" & trsh2), Sheets("LastWeek").Range("$A:$P"), 15, 0), "")
End Sub

Sub lookupcomments()
Dim tr3 As Long
Dim trsh3 As Long
tr3 = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
trsh3 = Sheets("ThisWeek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("P2:P" & tr3).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("L2:L" & trsh3), Sheets("LastWeek").Range("$A:$P"), 16, 0), "")
End Sub
```

this how the Basic data of my sheet Looks like. I always take the data from database and paste in this way
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Khp2.png)

First half is the Image of the second sheet. I call this sheet as last week. This sheet has an extra column E and F with Actions and no Actions evaluated. For now, this sheet is taken from the calculations of last week. in column G i have an formula, which calculates the CW. below is the sample Image of my third sheet, i call this as this week. In column G again i have an formula that calculates the CW. Here i use the first code, which always copy the Status with red to my this week.then, I use  lookup codes to look into the ID in column A (as per dumy sheet) and copy the Actions and no Actions, accordingly.
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgU9q.png)

Now what i would like to have is, an button in my Basic sheet, and when i click the button, it should delete the last week and update the data of this week to last week . This week data should be deleted.

Later i have an button in my Basic sheet, which will include all the codes i have in the post and i could calculate for the new set of data. I have half done and left with other half struck how to achieve. Could someone help me achieve this. I would be thankful to you. and would improve myself with programing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What difficulties you are facing while updating the last week sheet data from present week?

Comment: @Gowtham Shiva I dont know.. how to frame a code... in such a way that.. everytime I press a button,my last sheet data should be updated by the data of this week. And thisweek data should be deleted and updated by the  new result

Comment: Sorry.I am learning Vba. And sorry that I ask such direct question.I wanted to learn... And that's why I get my ideas and doubts clarified in this forum

Comment: please provide sample data with examples here. It would help us to help you. I am not able to assume things with the problem you have given

Comment: Sure, I will post an sample data in couple of minutes

Comment: @GowthamShiva I have updated my post with Images and Explanation, Please let  me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @GowthamShiva could you help me to Frame the code ?

Comment: Use `Range.ClearContents` in the button code. When you click the button, the range in lastweek sheet will be cleared, next it has to copy from currentweek to lastweek, then again use Range.ClearContents to clear the current week. Let me know if you are not able to do it.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-clearcontents-method-excel

Comment: @GowthamShiva ya, I will try and let you know

Comment: @GowthamShiva Clearing the Contents works. but how do i code to move the data of current week to last week  ?

Comment: use `Range.Copy Destination` to move the contents. After its moved clear the source data using clear contents.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel

Comment: Ya, will work on it and let you know, how it works ... Thank you. I thought it was so complicated.. but you made it in easy way

Comment: @GowthamShiva Can you suggest me how i can assign the Sheets in my lookup code. Because, the code executes only when i am in that page, i want the code to execute from the other sheet. How can we set the worksheet with my code ?

Comment: @GowthamShiva For some reason, my lookup codes are not working :( Could u tell me what would be the reason  ?

Comment: `Sheets("ThisWeek")` using this you can operate sheets from other sheets

Comment: Thank you. everything is perfect

Comment: Thats nice to hear! I have updated the same as an answer as it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as it worked for you,

- Use `Range.ClearContents` to clear the data in your `lastweek` sheet
- Use `Range.Copy Destination` to copy the data from `presentweek` to `lastweek`
- Clear the data in `presentweek` using clear contents.

You can use `Sheets("ThisWeek").Range("A1:B10")` (example) to operate different sheets with the same macro.